# legends not print fully when multiple plots are plotted on same figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have the code as below to plot multiple plots on the same figure

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25, 10))
def wl_ratioplot(wavelength1,wavelength2, dataframe, x1=0.1,x2=1.5,y1=-500,y2=25000):
    a=dataframe[['asphalt_index','layer_thickness',wavelength1,wavelength2]].copy()
    sns.scatterplot(x=a[wavelength1]/a[wavelength2],y=a['layer_thickness'],data=a)
    ax.set_xlim(x1,x2)
    ax.set_ylim(y1,y2)
    leg = "{} vs {}".format(wavelength1,wavelength2)
    print(leg) #this line is only to see the variable legend has the proper content
    ax.legend(leg)
wl_ratioplot(wave_lengths[2],wave_lengths[0],dataframe=train_df_wo_outliers,x1=-.1,x2=3)
wl_ratioplot(wave_lengths[0],wave_lengths[1],dataframe=train_df_wo_outliers,x1=-.1,x2=3)
wl_ratioplot(wave_lengths[3],wave_lengths[1],dataframe=train_df_wo_outliers,x1=-.1,x2=3)
wl_ratioplot(wave_lengths[3],wave_lengths[0],dataframe=train_df_wo_outliers,x1=-.1,x2=3)
wl_ratioplot(wave_lengths[2],wave_lengths[1],dataframe=train_df_wo_outliers,x1=-.1,x2=3)
```

I get the plot as the below pic where the legend seems to be first 5 letters separately even though the variable legend has the right content
[image]

There was another similar question & the solution was to put a square bracket to the variable legend. I tried this with the code as below.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25, 10))
def wl_ratioplot(wavelength1,wavelength2, dataframe, x1=0.1,x2=1.5,y1=-500,y2=25000):
    a=dataframe[['asphalt_index','layer_thickness',wavelength1,wavelength2]].copy()
    sns.scatterplot(x=a[wavelength1]/a[wavelength2],y=a['layer_thickness'],data=a)
    ax.set_xlim(x1,x2)
    ax.set_ylim(y1,y2)
    leg = "{} vs {}".format(wavelength1,wavelength2)
    print(leg)#this line is only to see the variable legend has the proper content
    ax.legend([leg])
wl_ratioplot(wave_lengths[2],wave_lengths[0],dataframe=train_df_wo_outliers,x1=-.1,x2=3)
wl_ratioplot(wave_lengths[0],wave_lengths[1],dataframe=train_df_wo_outliers,x1=-.1,x2=3)
wl_ratioplot(wave_lengths[3],wave_lengths[1],dataframe=train_df_wo_outliers,x1=-.1,x2=3)
wl_ratioplot(wave_lengths[3],wave_lengths[0],dataframe=train_df_wo_outliers,x1=-.1,x2=3)
wl_ratioplot(wave_lengths[2],wave_lengths[1],dataframe=train_df_wo_outliers,x1=-.1,x2=3)
```

Now I get the full legend but only the first legend is shown as the pic below
[image]

Can someone let me know how to get the full legend for all the plots? Thanks.

dummy data (the plot in pic will NOT match)

```
14nm    15nm    16nm    17nm    18nm    19nm    layer_thickness
1   2   3   4   5   6   0
1   2   3   4   5   6   0
3   5   7   9   11  13  5700
1   2   3   4   5   6   0
3   5   7   9   11  13  8600
1   2   3   4   5   6   0
3   5   7   9   11  13  5000
1   2   3   4   5   6   0
45  55  65  75  85  95  100
1   2   3   4   5   6   0
8   15  22  29  36  43  16600

wave_lengths=['15nm','16nm','14nm','18nm']
```

**Answer Update**
Based on answer from Quang Hoang. The output pics using scatter plot from matplotlib & sns.scatterplot

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just curious, why `sns.scatterplot`? Also can you share some data?

Comment: The current way you are calling the function you seem to be overwriting the existing ax.legend whenever you call `wl_ratioplot` instead if extending the legend

Comment: @QuangHoang, `sns.scatterplot` because it seemed intuitive to me. But if the same can be achieved with matplot directly, I can use that.  Added some dummy data.

Comment: @KaranShishoo I think so too, but i am not able to figure out how to fix it? Also, when I plot with varible `leg` without square bracket, all legends print (just the first letter)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `plt` it is pretty natural:

```
def wl_ratioplot(wavelength1,wavelength2, dataframe, 
                 x1=0.1,x2=1.5,y1=-500,y2=25000,
                 ax=None):
    leg = "{} vs {}".format(wavelength1,wavelength2)
    
    # set the label here, and let plt deal with it 
    # also, you don't need to copy the dataframe:
    ax.scatter(x=dataframe[wavelength1]/dataframe[wavelength2],
               y=dataframe['layer_thickness'],label=leg)
    ax.set_xlim(x1,x2)
    ax.set_ylim(y1,y2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25, 10))
wl_ratioplot(wave_lengths[2],wave_lengths[0],dataframe=df,x1=-.1,x2=3, ax=ax)
wl_ratioplot(wave_lengths[0],wave_lengths[1],dataframe=df,x1=-.1,x2=3, ax=ax)
wl_ratioplot(wave_lengths[3],wave_lengths[1],dataframe=df,x1=-.1,x2=3, ax=ax)
wl_ratioplot(wave_lengths[3],wave_lengths[0],dataframe=df,x1=-.1,x2=3, ax=ax)
wl_ratioplot(wave_lengths[2],wave_lengths[1],dataframe=df,x1=-.1,x2=3, ax=ax)
ax.legend()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This works! But i will still use `sns.scatterplot` because the mat plot scatter plot looks 'clunky'

Answer (score 2):

every time you call the function wl_ratioplot the legend is being reset the final value. use a array to store all the legends then access it all through a loop.

```
ax.legend([leg]) #it is resetting the legend after each call.
```

use a legends = [];

```
legends.append([leg])
```

after all function calls, draw the legend differently

```
ax.legend(legends)
```

Comment: This works. However, is there no way to do it within the function or plot itself?